# rails how to expire low level cached records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached, dalli

i want to cache my model objects in low level ( aka low level caching ) and I am doing this by `memcached` and `dalli`. i overloaded the find method in FOO class :

```
def self.find(id)
  Rails.cache.fetch('users/' , id) do
    User.find(id)
  end
end
```

the only problem here is about user updates. i want to expire that cache whenever the user is updated but i didn't find something like `Rails.cache.expire(key)`. is there any suitable to do this?

Comment: it seems like you are trying to replace the `db` with cache, not sure if that is a good idea. That said you can expire a key by calling `Rails.cache.delete(key)`

Comment: Definitely *not* a good idea - Rails already handles caching models pretty well, so even if you get this working, it's still probably not going to be an improvement.